# Set focus on lightning modal as soon as it opens in SF1

Tags: lightning-aura-components, salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform, popup, modal

I'm using salesforce lightning modal in a long form, everything is working fine when using lightning experience for desktop.

But when using a Salesforce1 in mobile, the form is not fitting into one screen, when a modal is triggered after scrolling down to a particular button, it appears somewhere in the middle and isn't visible until I scroll up.

I tried various custom CSS options, none worked.
Also, I wasn't unable to find any firm solution to this problem on the internet, hence posting here.

Is there any way to handle such scenario?

Comment: Hi Shri - did you figure out how to get focus to the modal?

Comment: Hello I haven't got any definite solution, as a work around I'm adjusting the view area of the modal by manipulating the css height according to the type of device.